# What would be the best method to obtain every prokaryotic psychrophile genome?

Tags: metagenome, wgs, bacteria

I am interested in running an analysis on the genome of every psychrophilic bacteria. Here defined as bacteria that have an optimal growth temperature at less than 15°C.

What would be the best way to go about collecting these?

I have yet to find a "growth temperature" filter on databases like NCBI. Though REBASE does include that (however obtaining the genomes from that site does not seem straightforward).

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up copying the GenBank (primary) column from the REBASE search results into an excel sheet. From there, I created a file with one accession per line called `Psych_Accessions.txt`. I then ran the following command using NCBI's command line tools.

```
epost -db nuccore -input Psych_Accessions.txt -format acc | efetch -format fasta > psych_genomes.fasta
```

Answer (score 2):

The database to use is BactoTraits. This will help either in the entirety or at least provide a solid starting point. Its here

[BactoTraits – A functional trait database to evaluate how natural and man-induced changes influence the assembly of bacterial communities](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X21007123)
by Aurélie Cébron (2021) Ecological Indicators 130

> We have created a user-friendly database of bacterial functional traits, thanks to the properties of **19,455 bacterial strains**. This database has been called BactoTraits. For example, oxygen preference, size and shape of bacteria, motility, optimum and range of pH and **temperature**, genome GC percent and trophic type are among the 19 traits included in BactoTraits. Based on the best-informed strains in the database, we identified five functional groups (i.e. mesophiles, competitors, colonizers, stress-sensitives and stress-tolerants) exhibiting a wide strain taxonomic diversity but with quite similar trait profile combinations.

Thus it's nearly 20000 species so your batteria should be there.

You can download the exact database [here](https://ordar.otelo.univ-lorraine.fr/record?id=10.24396/ORDAR-53). This is Univ de Lorraine's site, France. Its 9.4MB and called

> BactoTraits_databaseV2_Jun2022.csv

The supplementary information in the paper gives all the details for interpreting the database columns.

Given your skills in development you should have no trouble converting the **csv** format into a functional database and interrogating/querying it. My understanding of the paper is that the authors are microbiologists rather than coders, which in context is perfect.

---

Linking NCBI

BactoTraits contains two strain designations

- DSM no. (https://www.dsmz.de/collection/catalogue/microorganisms/catalogue)
- ATCC no. for example  ATCC BAA 1260 is [here on NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Taxonomy/Browser/wwwtax.cgi?mode=Info&id=364410) *Granulibacter bethesdensis*, which checks out on BactoTraits and is DSM 17861
- txid364410[Organism:exp]  is the SRA number from the above link ... so its all there, and here [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/?term=txid364410[Organism:exp]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/?term=txid364410%5BOrganism:exp%5D)

So ATCC links to NCBI links to the SRA and genome.

DSM are not necessarily available on NCBI, but ATCC will there. NCBI do have lots of databases for download, a database comprising ATCC to NCBI genome ... dunno, but *Entrez* will be able to link the ATCC (American Type Culture Collection)

Comment: While this is a great database for getting the names of psychrophiles, I was hoping for something that would tie temperature optima to NCBI project numbers or other direct genomic artifacts to make it easier to download. I will keep this question open for a bit longer before marking your answer.

Comment: Comment answered about below the line @donkey